# Wordpress Taxonomy Term Titles

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to display the title of a taxonomy term simply based on what the title of the taxonomy term is, NOT based on what posts are listed in the taxonomy.

Currently my taxonomy term and single post pages are displaying the titles of all taxonomies associated with each post.

For example...

1. I have a taxonomy called 'Residential', with a variety of terms associated with the taxonomy. Here's a link: http://desrosiers.robertrhu.com/residential/
2. There is a post called 'West Shore' that is associated with two taxonomy terms in the 'Residential' taxonomy, 'Renovations' and 'Contemporary'.
3. When I go to either the 'Contemporary' or 'Renovations' terms page OR to the 'West Shore' post, the heading lists BOTH taxonomy terms as the title. Here are some links: http://desrosiers.robertrhu.com/residential-category/contemporary/ and http://desrosiers.robertrhu.com/residential/west-shore/
4. So, if I click on 'Renovations', I want that page to only display the title 'Renovations'. If I click on 'Contemporary', I want that page to only display 'Contemporary'. And if I click on the single post in a particular taxonomy term, I want that single post to display the taxonomy term title that the post was navigated from.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the code for the taxonomy term archive page:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Residential Category Template
* Description: Template for Residential Project Types archive
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">

    <?php get_template_part( 'assets/partials/partial', 'mobilenav' ); ?>

    <!--Residential Taxonomy Header-->
    <div id="residential-heading-single"
         class="heading property-heading hide-for-small show-for-medium">
        <h3 style="border-right: none; padding-left: 0;">
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/residential/">
                Residential
            </a>
        </h3>
        <h1>
            <?php
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'residential_project_types' );
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo $term->name;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </h1>
    </div>

    <?php $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'residential_project_types',
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => true
    ) );

        foreach( $terms as $term ) :
    ?>

    <a class="property-thumb-link"
        href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
        <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">

            <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $term); ?>"
                 alt="<?php the_field ('category_image_alt', $term); ?>" />

            <div class="property-thumb-title">
                <h2>
                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the code for the single page:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Residential Single Template
* Description: Template for Residential Project Types single
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">

    <?php get_template_part( 'assets/partials/partial', 'mobilenav' ); ?>

    <!--Residential Single Header-->

    <div id="residential-heading-single"
         class="heading property-heading hide-for-small show-for-medium">
        <h3>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/residential/">
                Residential
            </a>
        </h3>
        <h3>
            <?php
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 
'residential_project_types' );
            if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                    echo '<a href="' .esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . 
$term->name . '</a>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </h3>
        <h1><?php the_field('project_title'); ?></h1>
    </div>

    <?php $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'residential_project_types',
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => true
    ) );

        foreach( $terms as $term ) :
    ?>

    <a class="property-thumb-link"
       href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
        <div class="property-thumb column medium-6 small-12">

            <img src="<?php the_field('category_image', $term); ?>"
             alt="<?php the_field ('category_image_alt', $term); ?>" />

            <div class="property-thumb-title">
                <h2>
                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the full taxonomy archive template. To get the correct term on the single-page you could use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and some regex - but you need a fallback if the post is accessed directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've edited my post to include the full code for both the tax term and single pages.

Comment: It seems that the first template is to display all terms of residential taxonomy and not the taxonomy archive. Maybe you could give this article a read: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Comment: That article is how I got to where I am. Not sure what info I am missing to do this correctly. Any chance you might point me in the right direction? Thanks!